# Why is FastQC not working after using Trim galore?

Tags: unix, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

I have a FASTQ file and I'm able to run the FASTQC program to analyse the file. but when I use `trim_galore`, FASTQC (or the FASTQC option in `trim_galore`) is not working anymore.

```
$ fastqc ./sub1_val_1.fq.gz
```

This is the output:

```
Started analysis of sub1_val_1.fq.gz
Analysis complete for sub1_val_1.fq.gz
Failed to process file sub1_val_1.fq.gz
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.SequenceLengthDistribution.calculateDistribution(SequenceLengthDistribution.java:100)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.SequenceLengthDistribution.raisesError(SequenceLengthDistribution.java:184)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Report.HTMLReportArchive.startDocument(HTMLReportArchive.java:336)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Report.HTMLReportArchive.<init>(HTMLReportArchive.java:84)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.analysisComplete(OfflineRunner.java:155)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Is the `Failed to process file` an error because the version is not correct between trim_galore and FastQC?

I [found this](http://seqanswers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-4846.html), but that wasn't that [helpful](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fastqc/+bug/1443275).

I'm using FastQC v0.11.5 and trim_galore v0.4.1.

I subsetted a library (reads in paired-end) using this:

```
seqtk sample -s100 ./SRR2937435_1.fastq.gz 10000 | gzip  > sub1.fastq.gz
seqtk sample -s100 ./SRR2937435_2.fastq.gz 10000 | gzip > sub2.fastq.gz
```

The `sub1_val_1.fq.gz` file was after passing `sub1.fastq.gz` into trim_galore. FastQC with `sub1.fastq.gz` is working.

---

**Note:** As suggested posted on [biostars.org](https://www.biostars.org/p/204664/).

Comment: Consider asking your bioinformatics-related questions at https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: I'm new to this, so thank you for your help redirecting me to the best place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: 
You have to uncompress it. Probably, `trim_galore` is only working with tar.gz and not fastq.gz.

```
gzip -d -k sub1.fastq.gz > sub1.fastq
y # to accept to overwrite
gzip -d -k sub2.fastq.gz > sub2.fastq
y # to accept to overwrite

trim_galore  --illumina --paired --fastqc sub1.fastq sub2.fastq
```